# How to set default country code in digits by twitter?

Tags: android, twitter, sms-gateway

I am using digits by twitter for login through phone number. 
http://digits.com/

How can I set the default country code? As I dont want users to scroll through all list of country codes as my major customers are from same geographical reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presently for android devices, if there is a sim card in the device, it shows the country code by default.

It is also possible to pre-load the phone number. Just add the permission,
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>`
to the AndroidManifest and Digits will pre-load the number for you.

Answer (score 1):

I [asked the same thing to Twitter's developer relationship team](https://twitter.com/andypiper/status/568418200414773248) - they are currently working on it, but there's no mechanism yet.